# Ruby tainted object returns not tainted string from to_s

Tags: ruby, security, oop

From ["Ruby Programming Language" - O'Reilly, Jan 2008](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516178.do)

> *Once an object is tainted, any objects derived from it will also be
>   tainted.*

Consider the following example code:

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end

end
```

If I run the following:

```
p = Person.new("John Doe")
p.tainted?        # => false
p.taint
p.tainted?        # => true
p.to_s            # => <Person:0x000000014e0600 @name="John Doe">
p.to_s.tainted?   # => true
```

everything's fine until now. The to_s method returns a string representation of the object and it is tainted as it is expected to.

I then redefine the to_s method like this:

```
class Person

  def to_s
    @name
  end

end
```

Now when I run the previous test again:

```
p.tainted?        # => true
p.to_s            # => "John Doe"
p.to_s.tainted?   # => false
```

The to_s method now produced a non tainted string. What am I missing here? Is there anyway to call super to retain functionality? Do I have to declare the returned string as tainted by myself every time I redefine a method, like this?

```
class Person

  def to_s
    self.tainted? ? @name.taint : @name
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would override Person#taint:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def taint
    @name.taint
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: as you said in #ruby-lang: "@name isn't "derived" from the object. it's a separate object(an attribute) that the person manages."